# How to get the count of Like, Shared... on post from Facebook account against the User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0, facebook-fql

I need to get the some fields value as, Number of Like on Post, Shared post, Number of comment post, Number of Post from Facebook account against the user in C#.

Just for more on update, I am using below code to fetch the above values, but in this scenario, if i pass Facebook account detail then its returning me all values as 0

```
 string urltxt = "http://www.groupon.com/deals/seattlehelitourscom-by-classic-helicopter-corp";

        System.Net.WebClient web = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string url = string.Format("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, click_count FROM link_stat where url='" + urltxt + "'");
        string response = web.DownloadString(url);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(response);
        ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs - this is not a place to get work done for free, tell us what you have tried so far, include your code. be specific and post where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Back to the docs.  You are building on a platform method that only has 1 year, 2 months, 3 days left to live.

On August 7th, 2016 v2.0 will be deprecated and all of FQL with it. Might want to look into the GraphAPI if you'll need this functionality after that time. [Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)